# Forming SQL Query for Detail and Subtotals (MySQL)

Tags: sql, mysql, subtotal

I have a common SQL task but can't find a clear path to the solution. I have a table, `downloads` with the `columns`, `download_date`, `image_file_id`, `credits`. What I want at the end is the detail, plus a subtotal of `credits` for the day at the end of each day. E.g.

```
2010-10-06 123456 5
2010-10-06 234567 20
                  25
2010-10-07 234678 15
etc.
```

I can use `SUM()` and `GROUP BY` to get the daily subtotals, but would love a convenient way to get a result set that contained both in the proper order so I don't have to scan the data again in the client code to arrange the subtotals with the detail rows.

Comment: Please post your current query as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will be able to accomplish this using the MySQL keyword ROLLUP:

```
SELECT download_date, image_file_id, credits 
    GROUP BY download_date, image_file_id WITH ROLLUP
```

or something similar.  For more details see [the MySQL manual.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html)

Comment: SELECT download_date, image_file_id, credits from downloads
    GROUP BY download_date, image_file_id WITH ROLLUP